# Convert NSDate to String in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a `NSDate` to a `String` and then Change Format. But when I pass `NSDate` to `String` it is producing whitespace.

```
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 let myString = (String(describing: date))
 formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 let yourDate: Date? = formatter.date(from: myString)
 formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
 print(yourDate)
```

Comment: show ur `date` , it is current date or else

Comment: its not Current Date, i am getting from Datepicker

Comment: show the `Datepicker` result

Answer (score 181, accepted):

you get the detail information from [Apple Dateformatter Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).If you want to set the dateformat for your dateString, see this [link](http://nsdateformatter.com/) , the detail dateformat you can get [here](https://waracle.com/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)
for e.g , do like

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
// initially set the format based on your datepicker date / server String
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let myString = formatter.string(from: Date()) // string purpose I add here 
// convert your string to date
let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
//then again set the date format whhich type of output you need
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
// again convert your date to string
let myStringDate = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)

print(myStringDate)
```

you get the output as

[image]

Comment: but date has no proper format we need to convert based on our reauirment

Answer (score 78):

I always use this code while converting `Date` to `String`  . (Swift 3)

```
extension Date
{
    func toString( dateFormat format  : String ) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }

}
```

and call like this . .

```
let today = Date()
today.toString(dateFormat: "dd-MM")
```

Comment: Easiest method by far. Date formatters are just object oriented programming when you don't actually need it.

Comment: `toString` reserved keyword. have to change it to something else. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I hate factory objects. Like why? Just let me call a method on the object. I think they were cool in the early 2000s.

Answer (score 25):

`DateFormatter` has some factory date styles for those too lazy to tinker with formatting strings. If you don't need a custom style, here's another option:

```
extension Date {  
  func asString(style: DateFormatter.Style) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = style
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
  }
}
```

This gives you the following styles:

```
short, medium, long, full
```

Example usage:

```
let myDate = Date()
myDate.asString(style: .full)   // Wednesday, January 10, 2018
myDate.asString(style: .long)   // January 10, 2018
myDate.asString(style: .medium) // Jan 10, 2018
myDate.asString(style: .short)  // 1/10/18
```

Answer (score 7):

Your updated code.update it.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let myString = formatter.string(from: date as Date)
let yourDate: Date? = formatter.date(from: myString)
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
print(yourDate!)
```

Comment: but yourDate is from type Data

Answer (score 5):

Something to keep in mind when creating formatters is to try to reuse the same instance if you can, as formatters are fairly computationally expensive to create. The following is a pattern I frequently use for apps where I can share the same formatter app-wide, adapted [from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/).

```
extension DateFormatter {

    static var sharedDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()   
        // Add your formatter configuration here     
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

Usage:

```
let dateString = DateFormatter.sharedDateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

After allocating `DateFormatter` you need to give the formatted string 
then you can convert as string like this way

```
var date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let myString = formatter.string(from: date)
let yourDate: Date? = formatter.date(from: myString)
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
let updatedString = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
print(updatedString)
```

OutPut

**01-Mar-2017**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension:

```
extension Date {

    func toString(withFormat format: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        let myString = formatter.string(from: self)
        let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
        formatter.dateFormat = format

        return formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
    }
}
```

And use it in your view controller like this (replace <"yyyy"> with your format):

```
yourString = yourDate.toString(withFormat: "yyyy")
```