# Date conversion from string not happening

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date within `order_date` in this format `May 31, 2018 at 3:35 PM`

I’m converting it to `Date` like so…

```
if let order_date = value["order_date"] as? String {

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: order_date)

}
```

But I'm getting `date` as nil. What could be the issue..?

Comment: [DateHelper](https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper) will help you

Comment: Is the date is at the format you give? I don't think so

Comment: change your dateFormatter like this "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"

Comment: @FredericP I'm sending in this format..`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. But in the server, some dates are in this format `May 31, 2018 at 3:35 PM`. Hence the issue...

Comment: @bwv - what the input you get and what the OP you expect

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Even if the format is `May 31, 2018 at 3:35 PM` I want it in this format...`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.`

Comment: @bwv - check the updated answer

Comment: Look at your date string. Now look at your date format. They are nothing like each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your dateformat is wrong change your format to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"
```

for e.g if you get the month as `Mar` then use - MMM, if you get `March` then use - MMMM

you can check the dateformat's in [here](https://waracle.com/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

for full answer

```
 if let order_date = value["order_date"] as? String {

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"
  var date = dateFormatter.date(from: order_date)
    if date == nil{
        dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        date = dateFormatter.date(from: order_date)
    }
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 let myStringafd = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
 print(myStringafd)

}
```

for detail dateforamt conversion you get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524651/convert-nsdate-to-string-in-ios-swift/42524767#42524767)

Comment: .@Anbu.karthik `"MMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"` won't be the format always. It could be `am` or `pm`

Comment: But @Anbu.karthik isn't `"MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"` always for A.M ? In my case it could be either AM or PM

Comment: @bwv - based on the time format it will change AM or PM , its the 12 hour dateformat

Comment: .@Anbu.karthik In the answer that you gave, should we not give an if condition to check for the date format..? because the date that I'll get in `order_date ` can be either in the formats `"MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"` or `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: @bwv - check the updated answer

Comment: Ok @Anbu.karthik Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below :

```
if let order_date = value["order_date"] as? String
    {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a"

        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: order_date)

    }
```