# Objective-C dateformatter. yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss change to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

How to getting Dateformat yyyy-MM-dd from string yyyy-MM-dddd hh:mm:ss

```
NSString *dateValue = self.selectedReward.expires_at;
NSLog(@"Date value --- %@", dateValue);
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateValue];
[cell.lblExpire setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",NSLocalizedString(@"lbl_Expired_On", nil),dateValue]];
NSLog(@"date %@", date);
```

> 2018-10-24 14:58:02.141296+0800 TKBakery[21601:277978] Date value ---2018-10-15 15:37:00
>
> 2018-10-24 14:58:02.141878+0800 TKBakery[21601:277978] date---- (null)

Comment: You set wrong format : yyyy-MM-ss instead of yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: thats one is a typo when i asking a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: @joey [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52962763/edit) the question and copy paste the exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you have clearly mentioned the date format also then why are used the wrong format

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//2018-10-15 15:37:00   
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateValue];
NSLog(@"date %@", date);
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *getFinalDate = [formatter stringFromDate:dateValue];
NSLog(@"final Date %@", getFinalDate);
```

for more info see this sample [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524651/convert-nsdate-to-string-in-ios-swift/42524767#42524767)

Comment: thank you. its exactly what i want. try to change string to date with different format isn't working.

Comment: @joey - which line you mentioned `try to change string to string is not working.`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to date with proper format then change that date to string with the format you need.

Change the code as follows:

```
NSString *dateValue = self.selectedReward.expires_at;
NSLog(@"Date value --- %@", dateValue);
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; //change the format
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateValue];
//add this:
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ss"];
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[cell.lblExpire setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",NSLocalizedString(@"lbl_Expired_On", nil),dateStr]];
NSLog(@"date %@", dateStr);
```