# date is not showing after convert the string to date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have strings and converting into the date format, but when I convert after the date is showing properly but time is showing the wrong format

> firsDateString : 2019-Mar-15 9:00 AM
>     secondName     : 2019-Mar-15 8:00 PM

String convert into the date format

```
let addedDate = firsDateString
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm  a"
let date1 = formatter.date(from: addedDate)
print("DATE \(date1)")
```

After that am getting this values:

```
DATE Optional(2019-03-15 03:30:00 +0000)
```

How can get the correct date format?

Comment: date does not return the exact value its the timezone issue, what the OP you expect

Comment: `print` displays dates always in UTC and the formatter considers the local time zone which is apparently +04:30 or +05:30

Comment: You live in India where there is a 5:30 difference from UTC? no? So what's wrong?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik tq for response 2019-Mar-15 8:00 like this

Comment: Try setting the timeZone of formatter like - formatter.time - TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!

Comment: @User1985 - you wanna OP as like `2019-Mar-15 8:00` and `2019-Mar-15 9:00`

Comment: Objects of the class Date has no format, if you want to print your `date1`object in a given format you need to use the DateFormatter  again.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes need like that

Comment: @User1985 Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477989/10150796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like , but is not a valid answer may be it works based on your condition but follow option2 it will cover all scenario if you need

<s>let formatter = DateFormatter()</s>

<s>formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm a"</s>

<s>let date1 = formatter.date(from: "2019-Mar-15 9:00 AM")</s>

<s>formatter.amSymbol = ""</s>

<s>formatter.pmSymbol = ""</s>

<s>let currentDateStr = formatter.string(from: date1!)</s>

<s>print("currentDateStr (currentDateStr)")</s>

based on @JoakimDanielson point

> How can this be the accepted answer when you no longer can tell the difference between 8 in the morning and 8 in the evening

here you need to follow the 24 hour format ,  I update my answer ,

**Option 2**

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm a"
    let date1 = formatter.date(from: "2019-Mar-15 9:00 AM")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm"
    let currentDateStr = formatter.string(from: date1!)
    print("currentDateStr \(currentDateStr)")
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @User1985 How can this be the accepted answer when you no longer can tell the difference between 8 in the morning and 8 in the evening?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - your question is sounds good, we will discuss with questioner

Comment: @User1985 - one more question how will you differentiate the morning and evening in 12 hour format if you use

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik You should convert it into 24 hours format from 12 hours instead of excluding the AM/PM symbol.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - no I am not copied, see my old answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524651/convert-nsdate-to-string-in-ios-swift/42524767#42524767

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    let addedDate = firsDateString
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = (NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm a"
    let date1 = formatter.date(from: addedDate)
    print("DATE \(String(describing: date1!))")
```

Comment: user expecting as like `2019-Mar-15 8:00` not `2019-Mar-15 8:00 PM`